# Find the view on the last position of RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

The below code is to find the view on the first position. How do I find the view on the last position?

```
TextView textView = 
  (TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV); //this is first position
```

here is my xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
```

Comment: use your recyclerview size or length

Comment: @jigarsavaliya Can you give example code please? I will immediately accept the working answer.

Comment: provide your adapter

Comment: not xml the full code of where this line is `TextView textView = 
  (TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV); //this is first position`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this**

```
TextView textView =(TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount()-1).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

**try this**

```
  TextView textView = (TextView) myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(arraylist.size()-1).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

**or try this**

simply you can do this:

```
if(position == YouList.size()-1)
{
  /*lastItem*/
}
```

Comment: it the list that you pass in your recyclerview adapter class

Comment: @NileshRathod please update your answer with the full code so I can accept it :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean so please add the full code

Comment: I don't have an `arrayList`

Comment: than what do you pass in your Adapter class

Comment: @JonathanDoe  provide your recyclerview adapter class with question

Comment: Where do I find it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150719/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-jonathan-doe).

Comment: here's myproject: https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-android/tree/master/android

Comment: does it have Recyclerview Adapter class ?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView =(TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Arraylist.size()-1).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

Comment: `Arraylist` is red in my project.

Comment: put your adapter of recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(myRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

Comment: I get error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference`

Comment: With `0` it works: `TextView textView = 
      (TextView)myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTV);` But your code crashes.